# Parametrize a test over an iterable fixture result

Tags: python, pytest

I have a fixture that sets the top-level directory, another fixture that returns a list of files in that directory, and a parametrized test on each of the files passed.

The problem is that I can't call `filenames()` without an argument inside the `parametrize() even though the`output_dir` could otherwise be filled in by pytest from the session fixture.

```
TypeError: filenames() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Code:

```
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def output_dir(tmpdir_factory):
    dir_object = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('out')
    return str(dir_object) + '/'


# test_files.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def filenames(output_dir):
    return glob.glob(output_dir + '*.csv')


@pytest.mark.parametrize('filename', filenames())
def test_file_is_good(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        assert f.read()
```

In this particular example there are various ways around the problem, but I am looking for an solution to the problem rather than a way around it.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish. It seems like you have a situation where some tests (which are not shown here) are creating files in the temporary directory. These files are then validated by `test_file_is_good`. Is that correct?

Comment: @ddavella Yes that's right.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a great way to handle this scenario in pytest. Why can't you just validate your files in the tests where they are created?

Comment: @ddavella They're created in a session-scoped fixture, and many tests need to be run against them.

Comment: Can you programmatically determine the names of the files that will be created? In other words, is there a function that will generate the names of all the files that will be created?

Comment: @ddavella Not without some significant changes. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161761/discussion-between-ddavella-and-hatshepsut).